# Type 'Observable<false>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: typescript, boolean

We are using Knockout.js (v3.5.0) and its TypeScript definitions. They worked OK until TypeScript 4.6.2. However the problem seems to be "deeper" than in the definitions file. It seems that there was some change in TypeScript in handling a boolean type. So rather than tagging this question as Knockout.js problem, I created small example of code inspired by the Knockout d.ts that illustrates the problem:

```
interface Observable<T>
{
  (): T;
  (value: T): any;
}

function observable<T>(value: T): Observable<T>
{
  return undefined as any;  // the implementation is not important
}

const x: Observable<boolean> = observable(false);
```

This code has one compilation problem:

```
Type 'Observable<false>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.
```

Of course casting the `false` as `boolean` works, but I do consider this as hack, not a solution (obviously we need cast on every occurrence of true/false).
Any way to actually solve this?

Edit: based on comment it is obvious that some type checking was changed. More examples can be seen here. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMDO0Bud0A2EAPACoB8AUAN6XLIAUAlAFzKkDcdjeBArhDalWyOCACeXAL6VKMPiARhgAexDIVWXPiJlyDXgKEiM2KHkIkKNblAhg+UdQoAmEGKAgvRmURI70APSByGAAFijAALYADkRREOBwymrIwL4gKmBpsSpQYGJglDKUYOIxKAAKcOIJ4ACy9mEq3gC8yADkCHCYYR3IAD6d3VAuHQGyCGqY2QAebKbalsToKipEYuTI7ZpmFkQM8ATYTFxTIDPI4gta5jok1bWJYI3hLVs7t-sQDF09fadkJRzpcAF43Pb3YggPhRdDQADaAF0PhovvcGMjAUA).

Is there any info (with explanation) for this change?

Edit2: as suggested in comments, I filed a bug report at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48150

Comment: I'm not sure what `observable(false)` does. Are you trying to assigne a boolean to an `Observable` ? If yes, you might use `of(false)`.

Comment: The x is observable variable, that means that its "inner" value is boolean and initially set to false = `observable(false)`. This concept is from Knockout. However the implementation is not important here, nor the interface name. This example should only illustrate the compilation problem. I left the interface name unchanged for better understanding for those who knows knockout.js.

Comment: We're seeing this too. Here are some more examples of errors to append to your code:
type PaymentMethod = 'cash' | 'card';
const y: Observable<PaymentMethod> = observable('cash');
const z: Observable<number[]> = observable([]);

Comment: This doesn't seem to correspond to any change mentioned at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/ -- and certainly not to either of the changes under "Breaking Changes" -- so I think it's a bug. So it's worth looking through https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues to see if it's already been reported, and -- if not -- report it yourself.

Comment: Interestingly, `const w: Observable<any> = observable(false);` works fine, and when I hover over the `observable` bit, I see `function observable<boolean>(value: boolean): Observable<boolean>`. So the Playground recognizes that `observable(false)` returns an `Observable<boolean>`  when you write `Observable<any>`, but not when you actually write `Observable<boolean>`.

Comment: There is an issue tracking a possible future fix for this at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [user](https://github.com/whzx5byb) who has responded to the Github issue (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48150) the Typescript 4.6 compilation error is expected:

> I believe this is a correct error which was not handled properly in old versions.
> The generic parameter T is invariant as it is used in both a covariant position () => T and a contravariant position (value: T) => any.

which is indeed true. Since user helped solve the problem, for sake of completeness I will try to rephrase and summarize his comments here.

The first proposed solution solves the problem only partially:

```
function observable<T>(value: T extends infer U ? U: never): Observable<T>
{
  return undefined as any;  // the implementation is not important
}

const x: Observable<boolean> = observable(false); // no error
```

however that will produce `unknown` type without a type annotation.

```
const bad = observable(false);
//     ^ unknown, which should be Observable<boolean>
```

The correct solution seems to introduce another type parameter

```
declare function observable<T, U = any>(value?: T extends infer R ? R : U): 
    unknown extends T ? Observable<U> : Observable<T>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=5&ssc=18&pln=5&pc=127#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMDO0Bud0A2EAPACoB8yA3gFDLIAUAlAFzKkDcdjeBArhDalWyOCACeXAL40AJhAQE4UFDD4gEYYAHsQybVlz4iZADTIAqsgC8oieQa8BAfiHIIAD0ghZmZKBhoZAAlZGcQ5DYLEXUAaxBtAHc9T29fdjC0Qyg8QhILSjYMbBzjEgouGjBxAAcUAAU4cQBbCHAAWQgwAAttWRtkAHIEOExuweQAHyGRqFlBjmQaGgRdTDBkDyLs3JN0bW0iMUpbAxLdiAZ4AmwmLg8GdXkYUAhZO-oAek-kVagVTTuf7aKA0B5gKACO5gq5wG4QaEPACMH2+vxBAI20CgIOWqxA62Q4m25zKxEaLTaYE6PT6U2QTwgLxAbxO+h2ZQYw1G4w+NHEDAARLNZILoQLhTyxVwBYzmW9xQwUcg0X9MUCcaCVmsNgAvElGPLEEB8ZroaAAbQAumyzoaiAxrXzdY6rUwaC6LUjTAAmN0ex2CuCCt1fH5qhRY4FQJbagkbACOAztpSN+0OEDE9Llr1kDmhCcePiZuYLDAhUK4heutyrStR4YxkY1uLjhJjpw5eVh8OhUCLz1Li1VTcB2Nx-ZrCK4-Yr05o-ZRw8b-2b461RA2NWTXYd3LGg2hNSFIulNGPkrGZ4vhGMd+lYfRq805kwoCQ-g2wD86ygoAA5ue9Yqiu6rrssm6iDupLdtCcD1lw8E5iy7wcEAA)

As the main issue was with the Knockout.js library, I filed the issue there (https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2589), hopefully someone with enough Typescript knowledge will correct the problem.

Comment: I think the answer by @martin-s is preferred as it ensures `observable` returns the desired type. There's no need to explicitly set the type of the variable.

Comment: It is not as simple as that. Very often we use generic `Subscribable` as a field in classes. Then subclasses concretely implements it as `observable`, `pureComputed` or whatever needed.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to instead explicitly specifying the generic type like:

```
const x = observable<boolean>(false);
```

The reason for this is that we are **assuming** that `false` implies `boolean`. Usually it does, but not always. Imagine e.g. these types

```
const x = observable<false | undefined>(false);
const y = observable(false);
```

(For anybody trying to solve the typing problem in any other way, please make sure that the above lines are also valid.)

Comment: Although this is only partial solution and you have to replace every declaration `observable(false)` with `observable<boolean>(false)`, it is better than casting every usage. So bounty deserved. Anyway, the complete solution without changing anything in the user code is preferred, all ideas are summarized in my own answer.